Complete space relative to specific norm
Let $X=\{f\in C^1([0,\infty, \mathbb{R})): \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(t)}{1+t}=\lim_{t\to\infty} f'(t)=0\}$. How to prove that $X$ is Banach space, if norm is defined as
$\|f\|=max(\sup_{t\geq 0}\frac{|f(t)|}{1+t},\sup_{t\geq 0}|f'(t)|)$. I checked properties of norm, and it is norm indeed, but I'm having trouble with proving that every Cauchy sequence converges. What can I conclude from $\|f_n-f_m\|<\varepsilon$, for $\varepsilon>0,$ $n,m>n_0$, that will justify that $\|f_n-f\|<\varepsilon$, for $\varepsilon>0,$ $n>n_0$? I have done similar problems when completness of $\mathbb{R}$ is used, but can't see how to use that trick here.
Any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance.

I have separated and numbered my steps $1$-$3$. I've done this so you have the option to look at how I begin the solution and then complete the rest before/without reading my later steps.


Getting a candidate limit


For any $T>0$, we know $C^1([0,T],\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space with the norm $$\|f\|_T=\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|f(t)|+\sup_{t\in [0,T]}|f'(t)|.$$  Furthermore, for $f\in X$, $f|_T\in C^1([0,T],\mathbb{R})$ and $$\frac{1}{1+T}\|f|_T\|_T \leqslant \|f\|\leqslant \|f|_T\|_T.$$ Therefore if $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset X$ is $\|\cdot\|$-Cauchy, then for each $0<T<\infty$, $(f_n|_T)_{n=1}^\infty$ is $\|\cdot\|_T$-Cauchy (and therefore $\|\cdot\|_T$-convergent) in $C^1([0,T],\mathbb{R})$.  Let $g_T$ be the $\|\cdot\|_T$-limit of $(f_n|_T)_{n=1}^\infty$. Since $\|\cdot\|_T$-convergence implies pointwise convergence, for any $0<t<S,T$, $$g_S(t)=\lim_n f_n|_S(t)=\lim_n f_n(t)=\lim_n f_n|_T(t)=g_T(t).$$  Therefore there exists $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g|_T=g_T$ for all $0<T<\infty$. Of course, this means that $g$ is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$ with continuous derivative. Also, it follows from the properties of $\|\cdot\|_T$-convergence that $g'$ is the pointwise limit of $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. We need to show that this $g$ is in $X$ and is the $\|\cdot\|$-limit of $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$.


Showing the limit is in $X$.


To that end, fix $\varepsilon>0$. Using the Cauchy condition, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n\geqslant n$, $\|f_m-f_n\|<\varepsilon/4$. Since $f_N\in X$, there exists $0<T<\infty$ such that for all $t>T$, $$\max\Bigl\{\frac{|f(t)|}{1+t},|f'(t)|\Bigr\}<\varepsilon/4.$$ By the definition of the $\|\cdot\|$ norm, and since $g(t)=\lim_n f_n(t)$ and $g'(t)=\lim_n f_n'(t)$, it follows that for any $t>T$, $$\frac{|g(t)|}{1+t}=\lim_n \frac{|f_n(t)|}{1+t}\leqslant \frac{|f_N(t)|}{1+t}+\|f_n-f_N\|<\varepsilon/2.$$  Similarly, $$|g'(t)|=\lim_n |f_n'(t)|\leqslant |f'_N(t)|+\|f_n-f_N\|<\varepsilon/2.$$  Therefore for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $0<T<\infty$ such that for all $t>T$, $$\frac{|g(t)|}{1+t}+|g'(t)|<\varepsilon.$$  This shows that $g\in X$.


Showing the sequence converges to the limit


We actually showed something stronger: For $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $0<T<\infty$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $t>T$ and $n\geqslant N$, $$\frac{|g(t)|}{1+t}+|g'(t)|<\varepsilon$$ and $$\frac{|f_n(t)|}{1+t}+|f_n'(t)|<\varepsilon.$$ By the triangle inequality, we have $$\frac{|g(t)-f_n(t)|}{1+t}+|g'(t)-f_n'(t)|\leqslant 2\varepsilon$$ for any $t>T$ and $n\geqslant N$. But since we already know that $g|_T$ is the $\|\cdot\|_T$-limit of $(f_n|_T)_{n=1}^\infty$, there exists $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geqslant M$ and $0\leqslant t\leqslant T$, $$|g(t)-f_n(t)|+|g'(t)-f_n'(t)|\leqslant \varepsilon,$$ so $$\frac{|g(t)-f_n(t)|}{1+t}+|g'(t)-f_n'(t)| \leqslant \varepsilon.$$
